# Swagger UI not showing responses examples

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

While using swagger-editor I create the below YAML that shows an example of the response object.  It's properly displaying in the swagger-editor.  When I then download the JSON and display it in swagger-ui, the example is completely missing.

```yaml
/person/{email}/create:
  post:
    summary: Create a new account
    tags:
      - Person
    parameters:
      ...
    responses:
      201:
        description: The new SQL ident and sport details 
        examples:
          application/json: |
            [
              12,
              [
                {
                  "sql_idnet" : 12,
                  "name" : "Basketball"
                },
                {
                  "sql_ident" : 13,
                  "name" : "Ice Hockey"
                }
              ]
            ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This *might* be because the response does not have a `schema` - in Swagger this means the response does not have a body.

That said, Swagger UI 3.0 displays this example correctly.

[image: JSON response example in Swagger UI]

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI and Swagger Editor currently do not support multiple examples. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2651) for updates.